# Building a striker

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder, striker

Okay, so I'm building a striker for one of my fellow players (the player is extremely new to DnD but is quite picky about what he actually wants to do).

Basically out of a team of 4 players, we have a leader and controller slot already filled so we'll need either a striker or a defender (probably striker for this guy).

What he requested for was a character whose sneaky/stealthy, interesting to play and is great in combat. From further study I believe he was interested in things like phasing/teleportation/invisibility/telepathy as part of his perks in his build and wants to be profficient with stealth and bluff (these two are kind of important). So far it all pointed towards warlock, but here is the big issue... He wants nothing to do with arcane or spellcasting in any way...

Now, I know that rogue and ranger have qualities which can answer his needs to an extent but he saw me playing rogue and his current character is a ranger, so he wants neither of the two.

Basically what I'm asking is advice over anything else, what can fit this guy the best based on what I pointed out above?

Comment: What is about "arcane or spellcasting" that bothers him? He lists 3 of the most iconic arcane spellcasting things as things he is interested in, so something tells me it's not the arcane flavor that bothers him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for you there are more strikers than classes of any other role. Unluckily, once removed the arcane ones (including gishes like the hexblade), the stealthy kind mostly falls into the rougueish category.

All my choices have Dex/Cha builds available, which makes them good at stealth and bluff (take a multiclass/training feat to gain in-class training where not otherwise available)

Option A is to play a Vampire. Vampires are not the best at dealing  damage but I hear they're good at never going down, which is a plus for the striker.
Assassin and monk I hear to be quite bad on damage and executioner relies a lot on the DM offering good hooks for some out-of-combat poisoning or so I hear.

Option B is to refluff the warlock, or a sorcerer, to be non-arcane. Just remove the arcane keyword with ewhatever he likes. Everything that works with arcane powers only works for those powers anyway, even if they lost the original keyword. Since he likes teleport and telepathy, calling it psionics might be a good choice.

Comment: Monk *can* be good if you go heavy on close bursts and can keep multiple enemies nearby without dying.

Comment: Hmm, so basically Hexblade is what you'd suggest... To be honest, thats the best solution I could come up with as well but the arcane portion of it was problematic so I came here, but refluffing it into something else could actually work! I'll give it a shot and pitch this concept to him and see what he says.

Comment: @Kiraya due to the almost non-existant ties between fluff and mechanics, refluffing is a great tool for playing the concept you want in 4e, provided your DM agrees. Anyway, non-arcane feylock (fey pact warlock) has teleport and invisibility right from level one.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Monks=minion killers when you have no controller.